# How do I use following xml query without prefix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, namespaces

In the following link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175178.aspx
I found this quote:

> "This prefix is then used in the query body instead of the namespace URI"

This makes me feel that if I do not specify prefix then I have to use uri in place of prefix. So please give me an example of using uri in place of prefix,
because in above link it is not given. Only they given example of with prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A namespace is meant to **separate identically named elements**. Very often XML fragments are just *glued* together. It is **very likely, that different elements with the same name get together**. By using a namespace the **combination of namespace and element name** is used to identify the element. But it is **not important, which *alias* is used to point to the namespace**!

You must distinguish between the "namespace" and the given "alias".

The following example has the element `<a>` in two flavours. Check this out:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root xmlns="DefaultNS" xmlns:dns="DerivedNS">
  <a>This is default</a>
  <dns:a>This is derived</dns:a>
</root>';
```

--no result

```
SELECT a.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/a') AS A(a);
```

--wildcard-namespace: Everything

```
SELECT a.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/*:root/*:a') AS A(a);
```

--Only default namespace declared: Only default element returned

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'DefaultNS')
SELECT a.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/a') AS A(a);
```

--.nodes() calls for the derived namespace: Only derived element returned

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'DefaultNS'
                          ,'DerivedNS' AS xyz) --Other prefix, doesn't matter
SELECT a.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/xyz:a') AS A(a); --prefix "dns" would not work, the alias is now "xyz"
```

--Here I use random prefixes. I took "dns" as alias for the default!

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('DefaultNS' AS dns
                  ,'DerivedNS' AS dns2) --random prefixes for the namespaces, took even dns for the wrong one!
SELECT a.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/dns:root/dns:a') AS A(a); --prefix "dns" returns the default ns now! And you need the prefix at `root` too!
```

--With inline declaration

```
SELECT a.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'declare namespace x="DefaultNS"; /x:root/x:a') AS A(a); --The alias "x" is now bound to the default namespace!
```

Comment: it was quite informative, thank u. i have copied the example and some discription which is creating doubt.      <pre> <code>       SELECT CatalogDescription.query('  
declare namespace PD="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ProductModelDescription";  
         /PD:ProductDescription/PD:Summary   
    ') as Result  
FROM Production.ProductModel  
where ProductModelID=19   <pre> <code>

Comment: this is the line which is creating doubt , please explain "This prefix is then used in the query body instead of the namespace URI"

Comment: @user3129097, This line (in my example it is `declare namespace x="DefaultNS"; /x:root/x:a`) defines an **alias for the namespace**. The namespace is `DefaultNS` (in your example its `schemas.microsoft...`) and the alias is `x` (in your example `PD`). This alias is uses as **namespace-prefix** in expressions like `/x:root/x:a` (in your example `/PD:ProductDescription/PD:Summary`). If this solves your issue, please accept my answer and vote it up, thx!

Comment: @user3129097, Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!